# How can I rename a tag in Delicious?

Tags: delicious, delicious-tags

Is there a way to rename a tag in Delicious?

Comment: Great, exactly what I was going to ask!

Comment: Need to change the accepted answer as delicious been changed a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Click Settings in the upper right.
2. In the Tags section of links, click Rename Tags.  [Direct link](https://secure.delicious.com/settings/tags/rename)
3. In the dropdown, select the tag you want to rename.
4. Enter in the name you want to rename to.
5. Done!

Comment: See the other answer. More recent.

Answer (score 4):

This has changed with the recent Delicious Re Design.

To rename a TAG, the new instructions are here:
https://delicious.com/help/merge-tags

Comment: This is the most appropriate with the current delicious version